# How can I submit form data after preventDefault is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little confused on how to take control of the submit event in a form, and I have tried to find a simple answer here.

I want to validate the form input *before* sending the form data to the form action scrip. I have tried to solve this by capturing the submit event, calling a validation script with Ajax, and if the validation succeeds I want the actual form procedure to be called. But I'm not sure how to proceed. Simply using `location.replace("action.php")` seems to fail (I guess that the form values aren't sent).

Here's the conceptual code:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  data = {
    the_input_val: $("#input_to_be_validated").val()
  };
  
  $.post("ajax_validate_input.php", data, function(data, status) {
    if (status == "success") {
      if (data == "invalid") {
        alert("Invalid input");
        // Form data is not sent... as expected
      } else {
        // Here I want to send the form data. But the event.preventDefault() prevents it from happening
        // What do I put here to call the form's 'action' script with form data? 
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="action.php">
  <input id="input_to_be_validated" name="my_input" type="text">
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Why validate the data on the server to then send the same data again to the server? Just submit the data. In case the data was not valid return the reason. If the data was valid than you're already done. No need to send the same data twice.

Comment: @Andreas... I find your comment as the best approach for my problem. I didn't think about processing the form data within the `ajax_validate_form` (or at least forward the data to `action.php`... I'll experiment with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Call the [`submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method on an [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) to manually submit the form without passing through the submit event again.

The form can be retrieved by reading out the `target` property of the `event` object.

Though, to make this work, lose the `name="submit"` value on your button, as this will cause an error trying to submit with the method.

```js
const $form = $("form");

$form.on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const data = {
    the_input_val: $("#input_to_be_validated").val()
  };
  
  $.post("ajax_validate_input.php", data, function(data, status) {
    if (status == "success") {
      if (data == "invalid") {
        alert("Invalid input");
        // Form data is not sent... as expected
      } else {
        event.target.submit();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="action.php">
  <input id="input_to_be_validated" name="my_input" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: And if you don't want to use `event.target` you can target the form directly, eg `$("form")[0].submit()` (note the `[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method like this:

```
if (status == "success") {
  if (data == "invalid") {
    alert("Invalid input");
    // Form data is not sent... as expected
  } else {
    event.submit();
  }
}
```